# How can I change build tools for projects in VS Code?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-code, g++

I want to build a C++ code but it errors. When I check the error message it's related with .NET. I have C# extensions but this isn't C# and I want to change this to g++ for C++ projects. I have g++ installed and added to path however I don't know how can I configure it to build with that for C++ codes.

Edit: I marked the answer as a solution but I also found an easier way for me:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc
cl.exe basically.

Comment: The best would be to use CMake with the CMake Tools extension.

Comment: So what do I need to do after installing the extension? It doesn't seem to work right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. One option (probably not the one you want to) is to build it from integrated terminal.
2. You can download c/c++ extension along with the cmake tools extension to have buttons for build/run configuration.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. However, if I want to do with terminal, how can I do that?

Comment: It's a little broader topic. If you want to compile single file, something like `g++ -o <output_filename> <target_filename>` should do the job. If you need to link any library you can pass the `-l <libname>`

Comment: If you want to understand the process, check it here: https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_54.html